# Stacked bar in R - reversed size and/or percent label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have taken this code from an open source, it is a part of an R Markdown Notebook, and it is supposed to render a stacked bar, and it does, but I think that it reverses the size and/or the labels that represent the percentage (picture attached).
I am new to R, any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
# Severity

data_severity <- data.frame(
  TIME = as.numeric(),
  SEVERITY = character(),

 PCT = numeric(),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for(i in 1:max(data$TIME, na.rm = TRUE)) {
  data_severity[nrow(data_severity) + 1,] <- c(i, 1, nrow(data[data$TIME == i & (data$SEVERITY >= 1 & data$SEVERITY <= 3),]) / nrow(data[data$TIME == i,]))
  data_severity[nrow(data_severity) + 1,] <- c(i, 2, nrow(data[data$TIME == i & data$SEVERITY == 4,]) / nrow(data[data$TIME == i,]))
  data_severity[nrow(data_severity) + 1,] <- c(i, 3, nrow(data[data$TIME == i & (data$SEVERITY >= 5 & data$SEVERITY <= 7),]) / nrow(data[data$TIME == i,]))
}

data_severity <- data_severity[order(-data_severity$TIME,data_severity$SEVERITY),]

data_severity$PCT <- as.numeric(data_severity$PCT)

 labels <- round(data_severity$PCT*100, digits=0)

 labels[
 labels<5] <- ""

 labels[
 labels != ""] <- paste(
 labels[
 labels != ""], "%", sep="")


ggbarplot(
  data_severity, 
  x = "TIME", 
  y = "PCT",
  fill = "SEVERITY",
  position = position_stack(reverse = FALSE),
  color = "white",
  legend = "right",
  xlab = "",
  ylab = "",
  ylim = c(0,1),
  title = "Perceived severity",
  subtitle = "Grouped results, originally rated on scales ranging from 1 (not severe)\nto 7 (very severe).\n",
  font.x = c(10, "plain", "#111111"),
  font.y = c(10, "plain", "#111111"),
  font.label = c(10, "plain", "#111111"),
  font.legend = c(10, "plain", "#111111"),
  font.tickslab = c(10, "plain", "#111111"),
  font.title = c(12, "bold", "#111111"),
  font.subtitle = c(10, "plain", "#111111"),
  label = rev(
 labels),
  lab.pos = "in",
  lab.col = "#444444",
  lab.size = 3.3
) + scale_x_discrete(
  name = "", 
  
 labels = waves
) + scale_fill_manual(
  name = "", 
  
 labels = c("not/less severe", "partly severe ", "more/very severe"),
  values = c("#9ab5c1","#ebedc8","#c1867b")
) + scale_y_continuous(
  expand = c(0, 0),
  breaks=c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1),
  
 labels = scales::percent
)
```

[image]

Comment: think you need something along the lines of `ggplot(data_severity, aes(x = factor(PCT, level = c("19", "27", "54")` to reorder your percentages

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it was the order of PCT labels, I found it being rev'd ...don't know why, I removed the `rev` function and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found what made the percentages upside down - the list (or vector) of labels was being reversed within the `ggbarplot` function, just removed the `rev` and it works fine.
it said:
`label =  rev(labels) ...`

Thanks to the community for editing my question, I felt welcomed.